# python program to read a csv and expand the range from a particular column

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a csv file which looks like this:

i need a new csv file which should have an extra column ranged
which should be like this:

im new to python(coding) and i have this project in my col
can someone help..

i need a desired out put which should not avoid zeros in the range and i need a python program

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with the amount of information we have, lets get started

```
import csv
```

well, this was obvious

```
def getAllVars(varying):  ## The input is a list here [start, end] both start and end are string which we will parse
    start = int(varying[0])
    end = int(varying[1])
    n = len(varying[0])
    exp = "{0:0"+str(n)+"}"  ## this expression will be used to pad zeros if output length is not matching
    res = []
    for i in range(start,end+1):
        res += [exp.format(i)]  ## just like I mentioned
    return res  ## so we return the expanded list
```

```
COL_TO_EXPAND=2
```

This constant to control which column to expand
Rest should be pretty simple

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open("outfile.csv","w", newline=""))
    head = next(csv_reader)   ## read header
    csv_writer.writerow(head+["ranged"])  ##write header to out file
    for row in csv_reader:    ## iterate over other rows
        toExpand = row[COL_TO_EXPAND]
        if "(" not in toExpand:
            csv_writer.writerow(row+[toExpand])
            break
        fixed = toExpand[:toExpand.index("(")]  ## extract fixed part
        varying = toExpand[len(fixed)+1:-1].split("-")  
        allVars = getAllVars(varying)  ## expand variable part
        for e in allVars:  ## iterate over the expanded range
            newRow = row+[fixed+e]  ## (why?)
            csv_writer.writerow(newRow) ## print it to out file
```

You can just put all pieces together and it works.

```
PS D:\my_projects\DemoProject> type .\test.csv   
id,name,range,status
1,paul,1234(0-2),failed
2,jerom,4321(000-002),passed
3,nanad,54(10-13),failed
```

```
PS D:\my_projects\DemoProject> type .\outfile.csv
id,name,range,status,ranged
1,paul,1234(0-2),failed,12340
1,paul,1234(0-2),failed,12341
1,paul,1234(0-2),failed,12342
2,jerom,4321(000-002),passed,4321000
2,jerom,4321(000-002),passed,4321001
2,jerom,4321(000-002),passed,4321002
3,nanad,54(10-13),failed,5410
3,nanad,54(10-13),failed,5411
3,nanad,54(10-13),failed,5412
3,nanad,54(10-13),failed,5413
PS D:\my_projects\DemoProject>
```

Comment: hi i forgot to add a thing i have updated the image.the thing is i can also have values without the range values it should be printed as it is in the updated image above.can u see to it pal. @Anubhav Sharma

Comment: im getting error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\python\range_extended_final.py", line 25, in <module>
    fixed = toExpand[:toExpand.index("(")]  ## extract fixed part
ValueError: substring not found

Comment: You can just add a condition before expanding and it would work. I will edit my answer